# Programmatically generate Inbound Email Service address

Tags: apex-email-service

I have an Apex class implementing Messaging.InboundEmailHandler.

Due to external constraints I have to use a new Email address for every Customer. If I am an administrator, I can define a new address each time I create a new Customer but I want to allow this for restricted Users.

so my questions are:

1. is it possible to generate new Inbound email addresses associated with one InboundEmailHandler class programmatically ?
2. if not, can non-administrator roles generate addresses manually ?
3. is there a limit how many addresses are associated with one InboundEmailHandler?